# How to include a default set of controls inside a TabItem in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles, controltemplate

I am learning `WPF`, its very confusing with all the `DataTemplate` stuff. I have a `TabControl` and inside it I will create many `TabItems`. There are two kinds of `TabItems`, ones that contain 1 `textbox`, and others that contain a `textbox` and a `listbox`.

Like so :

[image]

I make a dozen of these tabs, in different combinations, how can I make a template/pre-made control that I can say, I want to `TabControl.AddTab(style1)` and another time `.Add(Style2)`...

Is this possible? How should I go about doing it?

And secondary question, if this was accomplished, how would I reference say the `listbox` inside any one of the tabs if the name was auto generated?

Here are the two different types in XAML :

```
<TabItem Header="Style2">
    <TextBox IsReadOnly="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
</TabItem>

<TabItem Header="Style1">
    <DockPanel>
        <ListBox DockPanel.Dock="Right">
            <ListBoxItem>User1</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>User2</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
        <TextBox IsReadOnly="True" />
    </DockPanel>
</TabItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

In WPF, you can take advantage of the control's ItemTemplate (for header) and ContentTemplate (for content inside the tab) to control the content.

Define the dedired controls in a DataTemplate inside ContentTemplate.

**Here is an untested example:**

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AllTabs, Mode=OneWay}">
  <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=HEADERPROPERTY}" Margin="4,2,2,2" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
  <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SOMEPROPERTY}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SOMEOTHERPROPERTY}" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=SOMETEXTPROPERTY}" />
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

It is provided that the "AllTabs" property in the binding is an ObservableCollection containing a class which holds different properties for what you want to show. Like a String property (or more) where the Header is. And whatever you need to show in the content.

Comment: A datatemplate -inside- the contenttemplate? can you point me to an example?

Comment: Ok so I need an ObservableCollection with some sort of structure that holds items with a header and other properties... that part sinked in. Now, where would I be placing this XAML in your post? In the <Window.Resources>? From what Ive read so far ControlTemplates and Styles go there...

Comment: There are several ways. You can create a Style and put it in Window Resources or even App.xaml. Or you can create a CustpmControl or UserControl. Or simply use the XAML as it is in the example (with small adjustments), with the templates in the ControlTemplate and/or ItemTemplate.